# Is it possible to use iscsiadm from the same iSCSI server?

Tags: iscsi

I have sparse knowledge of iSCSI and hence I fear I'm missing the obvious.

I have set up a ZFS unit and I would like to export some LUNs.

The SCST daemon is listening properly on port 3260 and the scstadmin says the config is OK.
Whenever I try to run iscsiadm to check what the server show to the world iscsiadm doesn't send out anything

```
root@brunas:/# iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets --portal a.b.c.d --discover
iscsiadm: Login response timeout. Waited 30 seconds and did not get reponse PDU.

iscsiadm: discovery login to a.b.c.d failed, giving up 2
iscsiadm: Could not perform SendTargets discovery: encountered non-retryable iSCSI login failure
```

I took captures with tcpdump and iscsiadm is not sending out any single packet.

The only thing is that I'm sourcing the queries from the same host that runs the server, I do use an IP of an ethernet interface. Does the iscsiadm have to be run from a different host than the iSCSI server (I would be surprised) ?

Is there anyone who may give me a clue please?

Alex

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: There are no firewalls, it would be too simple, thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem disappeared by itself and I wouldn't know what was the root cause. For sure now I know that even from the iSCSI server I can login onto the target.